# how to remove space below sticky footer in HTML5?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working for responsive site and using twitter bootstrap. I am not able to fix footer in my site. Googled many sites found solution but it is not applying in my particular page. Not able to trace the problem. please check the [**code here jsdiddle**.](http://jsfiddle.net/8VZJ8/5/). I don't want any space below the footer.Thank u.

```
//css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
            margin: 0pt;
}

#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto; 
  margin: 0 auto -60px;  
  padding: 0 0 60px;
}


#footer {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is structured improperly.

The footer div must be outside of the wrap

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrap">

    <div class="container-fluid" style="padding-top:1%; padding-bottom: 1%;">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12 largecircle">

            </div>      
        </div>
    </div>


</div>

<div id="footer">      
    <div class="container-fluid"   style=" background-color:#cccccc; position: absolute;  opacity:0.7;">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <h1>Sticky </h1>
        </div>
        <p class="lead">Pin a fixed-height footer to the bottom of the viewport in desktop browsers with this custom HTML and CSS.</p>       
        <p>Use  if need be, too.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/bHg3H/1)

Comment: thank u for the solution. in jsfiddle it's working fine but i need to take the footer inside wrap. is it possible?

Comment: Why does the footer need to be inside the wrap? That should make no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is can fix your problem:

```
    #wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto; 
  margin: 0 auto;  
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry. still no change.

Answer (score 0):

Well that space is there because you have -60px margin

`margin: 0 auto -60px;`

Comment: it is, to counter-act `padding: 0 0 60px;`...its common idea to make div stretch to full space!! :)

Comment: still no change in the bottom space.

Comment: You can try using

`#wrap {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
   width:100%;
}`

Comment: @RaduVulcu: still space is there. did u check the jsfiddle link?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for: http://ryanfait.com/html5-sticky-footer/

Comment: i have tried samples like this. tested twitter bootstrap sample page also. they all r working good but not working in my page.

Comment: replace "margin: 0pt;" by "margin: 0;"